# Como limpiar la consola en java

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un programa en java y queria saber si se puede limpiar la consola y empezar a escribir desde el principio, incluso habiendo escrito algo antes.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido, deberías poner un ejemplo. Con código incluido o con alguna ilustración para que podamos ver a qué te refieres.

Comment: Ya probaste con `System.out.println("\f");`?

Comment: Recuerda que es importante revisar [ask] que te brinda información acerca de como formular preguntas en el sitio, agrega lo que has tratado o investigado. No olvides realizar el [tour]  del sitio, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consola NO es java.

Cuando ejecutas un programa por consola, Java ve un "OutputPrinter" donde puede enviar datos. Es el Sistema Operativo el que decide dónde se envian esos datos (que puede ser la consola, o un fichero, u otro proceso). Y es el programa de consola (normalmente parte del SO) el que decide cómo muestra esos datos.

Así que no hay una manera "Java" de cambiar la consola. Se pueden probar "trucos", como enviar 200 "System.out.println()" para que el texto actual se desplace hacia arriba, o códigos específicos (como el "\f") para que la consola los interprete (pero eso dependerá de lo que la consola quiera hacer con esos códigos, no lo controlarás desde Java).